# Windows dosen't see USB drive

Tags: windows, usb, windows-explorer, usb-storage

My machine won't see a Lexar USB drive in File Explorer or Disk Management but it will see it in Device Manager as in this snip: [USB drive appearing in Device Manager Screen Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoH0B.png)

As, I said, nothing appears in File Explorer: [USB drive not appearing in Explorer Screen Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR1pg.png) or in Disk Management: [USB drive not appearing in Disk Management Screen Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aldE.png)

The situation is weird, as Windows sees the drive in Device Manager and not in Explorer or Disk Manager. Any help appreciated in getting my USB in working order again.

Comment: So, no ideas about this issue?